# google map doesn't display in android. "App has unfortunately stopped" error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api-console

**We have tried to view google map preview in android using google map api from google API console.v2 The following code has been taken from google developer's site but app is giving error 'unfortunatelly stopped'**

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**ActivityManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gmap1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyDePgIDW-W2MBdiWJruYd_lkQsUu1y-EVM"/>
<meta-data 
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

**mainActivity**

```
package com.example.gmap1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
} 
}
```

Comment: can u post your logcat?

Comment: <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"

Use the qualified name of your activity. com.example.gmap1.MainActivity

I can't help more, post your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to add the folllowing lines in your manifest:

```
 <permission
        android:name="com.example.gmap1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gmap1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Give a try.